# Can a program next in a pipeline see the exit code of the previous program?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, exit

I would like to make a pipeline of Bash scripts like this

`prog1 | prog2`

such that prog2 can see the exit code of prog1 and act differently based on that information.

Is this possible?

Comment: Could you elaborate the _act differently_ part of your question?

Comment: You have limited control over how far `prog2` has progressed when `prog1` exits, due to the internal buffering used to implement the pipe and how `prog1` and `prog2` are scheduled.

Comment: Also look at [In what order do piped commands run?](unix.stackexchange.com/q/37508)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general answer is no. It's possible for `prog2` to exit before `prog1` even starts (obviously that can't happen if `prog2` actually reads some input, which you'd expect it to do if you're using it in a pipeline). It's definitely possible for `prog2` to exit before `prog1`; this happens for example when `prog2` is a search program that exits as soon as it finds a match, in which case `prog1` may not have finished producing all the data yet.

There is no direct way for `prog2` to retrieve the exit status of `prog1` or even to know that `prog1` has exited. All that `prog2` can know is that `prog1` has closed its end of the pipe, which it can do without dying.

If you want to obtain the exit status of `prog1` from `prog2`, there are two common methods: you can write it to a file, or you can send it through the pipe. Sending the output status as the last line of the piped data is a possibility. You have to make sure not to process the last line until you know that it's the last line, i.e. until you've tried to read the next line.

```
{ prog1; echo $?; } | …
```

Here's an example where the right-hand side is a text filter that colors every line containing the word “error” in red. If the left-hand side fails, the right-hand side exits with the same status.

```
{ prog1; echo $?; } | awk '
    NR != 1 {
        if (line ~ /[Ee][Rr][Rr][Oo][Rr]/) print "\033[31m" line "\033[0m";
        else print line;
    }
    {line = $0}
    END {exit($0)}
'
```

Comment: I was trying `{ command; echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}; } | sort | ...` so that the exit status comes first in the stream. It's all very interesting!

Comment: @illuminÉ That would only work if `${PIPESTATUS[@]}` is sorted before anything else in the output of `command`. If `command` prints out a bunch of numbers, or if it can print out arbitrary text, you're in trouble: you won't be able to distinguish its output from the status line.

Comment: Thank you, indeed it only succeeds at sorting a success status to top if the command doesn't contain 0 in its output lol. Tgif/s.

Answer (score 2):

Although you can in some special cases (see the other answers) you can't in every case. Some filter programs will just keep going, while others will hold all output, unleash it in a single blast, and then exit.

For an example of a "just keep going" program, `grep` will server, as would `tail -f /var/log/some_log_file`. Using `sort` in a pipeline causes a "stall", as `sort` will collect input until the pipe in front of it closes. Using `xargs` adds a further complication: are the programs started by `xargs` (it might start many instances) part of the pipeline or not?

Comment: -1 because you where upvoted for rationalising an incorrect answer.

Comment: @richard Huh? Bruce's answer is correct (although the second paragraph is a little confusing).

Answer (score 1):

The answer: Not directly.

@terdon has illustrated that the exit code of the previous command in the pipe must be sent as an explicit parameter to the next command.

Remember that the pipe is merely a mapping of the previous command's STDOUT to the next command's STDIN; exit codes are not outputted to STDOUT (or STDERR).

Comment: -1 because you where upvoted for quoting an incorrect answer, and not saying much more.

Comment: @richard fair enough... I should've double checked... that's what happened if I force myself to answer a question when very tired...

Answer (score 1):

All process, in pipeline, are started before any exit. Therefore `prog2` could have to get this info after it had started, it would also have to hold off processing until `prog1` had exited, this could stall the pipe. There seems to be fundamental problems in doing what you ask, not OS limitations.

You probably need to consider a temporary file, or putting the result in a variable.

Example for small amount of data, using a variable.

```
tmp=$(prog1)
if test "z$PIPESTATUS" == "z0"
then
   …
else
   …
fi
```

Comment: There's a gap in your reasoning. `prog2` is started before `prog1` completes in general, but there could be a way for it to receive the output status from `prog1` while it's running.

Answer (score 0):

To finish [Gilles’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/118661/23408),

```
(prog1; echo $? > /tmp/prog1.status) | prog2
```

is an approach.  `prog2` could either

- read standard input to the end, and then read `/tmp/prog1.status`, or
- check for the existence of `/tmp/prog1.status` periodically
  while reading the standard input.